# LineSegment.IsStroked missing in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, draw

In Wpf you can

```
<Path Stroke="White" Fill="#50ffffff" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="20,20">
                    <LineSegment Point="100,20" />
                    <LineSegment Point="100, 100" IsStroked="False"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="20, 100"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="20, 20"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

To get

[image]

Sadly in UWP there is no `IsStroked` property in the `LineSegment` class, is there any know workaround for this case?

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't this be achieved by simple removing the right segment? As long as there is only one gap and `IsClosed = false` this should work (you would have to reorder the lines of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To overcome this limitation, you should be able to break down the `Path` into multiple `Paths`, **skipping** the areas without stroke. In the sample code, you could even keep it as a single `Path` by starting in the upper right corner and continuing counter-clockwise, ending in the lower right corner.

In more complex scenarios, having multiple `Paths` is a bit less clean than in WPF, but it should be a functional solution.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there is only one gap, this should work too:

```
<Path Stroke="White" Fill="#50ffffff" StrokeThickness="2">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="100,20" IsClosed="False">
                <LineSegment Point="20,20"/>
                <LineSegment Point="20,100"/>
                <LineSegment Point="100,100"/>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: I see, the problem is that my real shape is more complex than this example